# eth0 interface disappears after router failure

Tags: networking, virtualbox, centos

I'm running CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-1511 over VirtualBox on a Windows 7 64bit machine. All the configurations are at its default values, except for VBox Networking, which is set to Bridge. I'm using DHCP.

The network is unstable and the local router reboots often. After a router reboot all network interfaces on other systems (Windows machines) work as normal, but eth0 just disappears from the CentOS machine.

How can I bring it to life again?

Comment: does ethtool see the interface? `ethtool eth0` if so, what state is it in (especially teh LinkDetected status)?

Comment: `ethtool` won't find the device. I'm new to CentOS, but apparently it uses a different network interface called enp0s3, I will read up on that.